Direct Sequence Spread Spectrum (DSSS) of Binary Phase Shift Keying (BPSK)
I need help coding Direct Sequence Spread Spectrum into my Binary Phase Shift Keying Code. DSSS is the main piece of my objective. The code provided is composed of Binary Information, Carrier Wave, BPSK, AWGN, Impulse Noise.
clc;
clear all;
close all;

N = 7;
I = randi([1], 1, N);
I = [1 0 1 0 1];

for V = 1:length(I) %Binary Phase
    if I(V) == 1
        nn(V) = 1;
    else
        nn(V) = -1;
    end
end

i = 1;
t = 0:0.0001:length(I);
for j = 1:length(t)
    if t(j) <= i
        y(j) = nn(i);
    else
        i = i + 1;
    end
end

Fc = sin(2 * pi * 2 * t);
x = y .* Fc;

% AWGN Noise
SNRdB = 10; % Adjust SNR as needed
snr_lin = 10^(SNRdB / 10);
noise_variance = 1 / snr_lin;
noise = randn(size(t)) * sqrt(noise_variance);
AWGN = x + noise;

% Impulse Noise Parameters
impulse_amplitude = 10; % Adjust the amplitude as needed
impulse_prob = 0.01; % Probability of an impulse at each time index
impulse_noise = zeros(size(t));
impulse_indices = rand(size(t)) < impulse_prob;
impulse_noise(impulse_indices) = impulse_amplitude;
IMPULSE = x + impulse_noise;


subplot(5, 1, 1);
plot(t, y);
axis([0, length(I), -2, 2]);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Voltage')
title('Transmitted Binary Information');


subplot(5, 1, 2);
plot(t, Fc);
axis([0, length(I), -2, 2]);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Voltage');
title('Carrier Signal');


subplot(5, 1, 3);
plot(t, x);
axis([0, length(I), -2, 2]);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Voltage');
title('BPSK');

subplot(5, 1, 4);
plot(t, AWGN);
axis([0, length(I), -2, 2]);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Voltage');
title('BPSK with AWGN Noise');

subplot(5, 1, 5);
plot(t, IMPULSE);
axis([0, length(I), -2, 2]);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Voltage');
title('BPSK with Impulse Noise');

BPSK PLOT IMAGE
I did try to code DSSS into the BPSK code along with the AWGN and Impulse Noise but results got errors, and no visible outputs in its plots or graphs.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please [edit] your post to show the, non-working, code you wrote for the DSSS and include the error message in the post? We cannot help you to debug code you haven't shown us, see [mre].

To add DSSS to your BPSK signal, you have to combine your data signal with a higher data-rate bit sequence (or code). Before you apply the tone you have to multiply your BPSK signal by the code, below I show a code for a chip rate (the ratio between code and data rates) of 10:
clc;
clear all;
close all;

N = 7;
I = randi([1], 1, N);
I = [1 0 1 0 1];

for V = 1:length(I) %Binary Phase
    if I(V) == 1
        nn(V) = 1;
    else
        nn(V) = -1;
    end
end

i = 1;
t = 0:0.0001:length(I);
for j = 1:length(t)
    if t(j) <= i
        y(j) = nn(i);
    else
        i = i + 1;
    end
end

%% DSSS
M = 10;
code = randi([0 1], 1, M);

code_nn = code*2-1;% Binary phase

% Code length = 1 BPSK symbols
code_y = repmat(code_nn, round(length(y)/length(I)/M), 1);    
code_y = code_y(:).';

code_y = repmat(code_y, 1, length(I));

% DSSS signal
y_dsss = y(1:length(code_y)).*code_y;

%%
Fc = sin(2 * pi * 2 * t);
x = y .* Fc;

Also, I recommend you to use repmat and similar function to create the Binary phase and the y signal, it will be faster. Just check the way I did for the code signal.
